# How to json with circular references?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following class construct creating a circular dependency. In general, `Jackson` library should be able to handle these circular dependencies.

I'm looking for a way to not having to use annotations on every class that has circularities, but somehow configure it generally in the `ObjectMapper`.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
abstract class Shape;

class Line extends Shape {
    //a line can only connect 2 circles
    Circle from, to;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    // a circle can have many lines connected
    List<Line> lines;
}
```

I then serialize a list, which contains both `circles` and `lines`:

```
List<Shape> shapes;

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().setDefaultTyping();
```

It is possible to configure the id generation globally on the mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since not all types can have ids (only POJO types, that is, `Collection`s, `Map`s and arrays are out), and since details may vary, there is no "default id" setting unlike with type ids.